# Query regarding vector transpose in hypothesis function (Stanford Machine Learning Video Lecture 2)

Tags: math, machine-learning, matrix, vector

I was looking at lecture 2 of the stanford machine learning lecture series taught by professor Andrew NG and had a question about something that I think might be quite rudimentary but is just not clicking in my head. So let us consider two vectors θ and x where both vectors contain real numbers.

Let h(x) be a function (in this specific case called the hypothesis) but let it be some function denoted by :

```
h(x) = "summation from i = 0 to i = n" of θ(i)*x(i) = θ(transpose)*x
```

I dont understand the last part where he says h(x) is also equal to θ(transpose)*x.

If someone could clarify this concept for my I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just basic linear algebra, it follows from the definition of [matrix vector multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General_definition_2):

[image]

So if θ and x are both n+1 x 1 matrices, then

[image: (θ' * x) = Sum over i θ'(1,i) * x(i,1) = Sum over i θ(i,1)*x(i,1)]

Comment: they are indeed thanks for that. I was over thinking it and looking past the basic formulae of matrix multiplication.